# Python to Exe Creating Input Formatting Errors

Tags: python, string, cmd, traceback

I've created a simple Python script that allows users to send text messages to phones via the phone emails all numbers have. I compiled to .exe so it would be more accessible by my friends, but after I compiled it I noticed that the .exe doesn't accept the input the way that the Python interpreter does. I've used the command:

```
address = input("What is the address?")
```

in order to take the response as a string and use it as a data value in the SMTP function shown later in the script:

```
import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
password = ["textFilter", "listCheck", "8*****ksd", "1231238dj", "312j38d", "12391jd", "1293ds", "12931d", "123c8we", "129ks9n2", "2139m2", "1s21231", "121i2m1", "16****on", "12983j", "231m8d9"]
spamActivate = True
messageSent = 0
modPat = 0
print "!Welcome to PySpammer v0.1 by CryptoFrost, all rights reserved to Damon %%%%% - 2014!\n\n"
print "To start using this program, you will need to know your target address. The address is an email linked to all" \
      " phones. It uses the target number and the line extension. For example, a Verizon line would use [number]@vtext.com." \
      " If you don't know the target address, simply have the target text an email that you have access to. Enter the" \
      " email, check the received message, and use the sender's email that you will use for this program." \
      " Here are a few known extensions:\n\n" \
      "* Verizon - [number]@vtext.com\n" \
      "* AT&T - [number]@txt.att.net\n" \
      "* Straight-Talk - [number]@messaging.sprintpcs.com (Straight-Talk uses a few different addresses)\n" \
      "* Sprint - [number]@messaging.sprintpcs.com (Yes, it's the same as ST)\n" \
      "* Virgin Mobile - [number]@vmobl.com\n" \
      "* T-Mobile - [number]@tmomail.net\n" \
      "* Nextel - [number]@messaging.nextel.com\n\n" \
      "Make sure to use the 10-digit number!"

address = input("What is the address?\n")


server.starttls()
server.login("thespamtasticbot@gmail.com",password[2])

msg = input("What is the message?\n")
while spamActivate:
      server.sendmail("thespamtasticbot@gmail.com", address, msg)
      messageSent = messageSent + 1
      modPat = modPat + 1
      print(messageSent, "total messages sent!")

# ["8******21@messaging.sprintpcs.com", "8********0@vtext.com", "******73@vtext.com", "*******08@vtext.com"]
```

When I compile this to .exe and run it, I enter the address and get this:
[image]

The only way I've been able to fix this on my own is to enter quotation marks around the address itself... but I don't want to have to do that (and I don't think the users would either). How could I format the text before it's entered so it will be used as a string (without having to format it to a string inside of the program)?

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.7.X strings are handled very oddly. Using python version 3.3.X will most likely fix it, but you will have to change some syntax. for example print is a function in 3.3 so you need brackets and extra stuff you can go here http://www.python.org/download/ to get the latest version of python.

This is the only solution I can think of.

Comment: I actually made the prototype of this program in Python 3.3.5, but I had to convert it into 2.7.6 because I couldn't find a valid .py to .exe converter, other than cx_freeze (which I have trouble with). I can try cx_freeze again, but if it doesn't work the method I'm using in the post is the only one available.

Comment: cx_freeze is relatively easy to use: here is an easy to follow tutorial to go off of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XHcDHSWRCRQ I tried it in 3.3.2 and it works fine, also works with modules.